# The algorithm behind makeblastdb?

Tags: blast, makeblastdb

> What is the algorithm/concept behind‚`makeblastdb`?

I know `makeblastdb` produces a `.phr`, `.pin`, and a `.psq` file, that represents an index or a data structure that is better optimised for searching a given query.

> What is exactly stored in these files?

Seems like `.phr` and `.pin` are storing some metadata (based on the size) and `.psq` the actual index.
It can't be the table of all k-mers since the command doesn't take a value of k? (or maybe it is fixed to 3)

I could not find any direct discussion of the algorithm since google is flooded with people asking how to build such a database...
Maybe someone can give me a link or hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at this publication ["Database indexing for production MegaBLAST searches"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2696921/) which although deals with MegaBLAST and it's indexing method, it would appear that this was rolled into the NCBI C++ toolkit as the command `makembindex` so I'm inclined to think the current implementation must have been derived from this strategy. Looking at the relevant part of the current NCBI C++ toolkit I find no reference to `makembindex` but only `makeblastdb` which I assume has superseded the older command: [blastdb Directory Reference](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/IEB/ToolBox/CPP_DOC/doxyhtml/dir_30f669065d6b13796daf8e29b61b0d9a.html)

Ulimtately the true details of the index generation lie in the C++ source code for `makeblastdb` can be found [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/IEB/ToolBox/CPP_DOC/doxyhtml/makeblastdb_8cpp_source.html).  However following on from that I think the further details of the index generation may be in one of the following files which are includes for the main `.cpp` file:

[`seqdb.hpp`](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/IEB/ToolBox/CPP_DOC/doxyhtml/blast_2seqdb__reader_2seqdb_8hpp_source.html)

[`build_db.hpp`](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/IEB/ToolBox/CPP_DOC/doxyhtml/blast_2seqdb__writer_2build__db_8hpp_source.html)

[`seqdbcommon.hpp`](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/IEB/ToolBox/CPP_DOC/doxyhtml/blast_2seqdb__reader_2seqdbcommon_8hpp_source.html)

[`writedb.hpp`](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/IEB/ToolBox/CPP_DOC/doxyhtml/blast_2seqdb__writer_2writedb_8hpp_source.html)

It would appear from `seqdb.hpp` that:

The index files have extension `.pin` or `.nin` and sequence files `.psq` or `.nsq`,

However it's not at all clear how the current implementation differs to the 2007 reference or where the `.phr` file is generated from!  Some degree of reverse engineering the C++ source code will be needed!

Comment: Thank you, i will read this! After a quick look, this datastructure is more or less a kmere list to position (hash/table), see 2.1.